# Jruby rails application on Tomcat. War generated through warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, warbler

I am using warbler to create war of my Jruby application. It creates a war without any problem, but when I deploy it in tomcat (webapps) it gives me following exception:

```
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/POC_Rails_1_3_1_/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Comment must start with "<!--".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
```

Generated (WEB-INF/web.xml) is below. Let me know if I have forgotten to configure something.

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>public.root</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>rails.env</param-name>
    <param-value>developement</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


</web-app>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>public.root</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>rails.env</param-name>
    <param-value>developement</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


</web-app>
```

Comment: If it's an exact copy of your web.xml, then obviously it's duplicated and thus a non-valid xml. Remove everything after </web-app> and try again.

Answer (score 1):

As the first commentor mentioned the xml is invalid because of `duplicate <web-app> and <!DOCTYPE`. The parser error is related to `<!`. `<!` is meant for declaring documenttype and it can appear only before the start of the root element. Any subsequent appearances will be treated as start of a comment. And the comment `needs -- after <!`